# How to pass variable from php file to jquery ajax file for its url parameter to be sent to another php file?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am a newbie in javascript,jquery,ajax. I have a problem with not working of my code.
so well my codes and my work description is described below. Can someone help me please.

I have hotjobs.php file and hotjobsoutput.js file and api.php file. In hotjobs.php file my code is like:

> Hotjobs.php:

```
<?php                                           
$sql=mysql_query("select * from hotjob"); 
$count=mysql_num_rows($sql); if($count>0){ while
($result=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){?><tr><td><?php echo 
$result['job_title'];?></td></tr><?php }}?>
```

Now I want to get a row datas from database when I click its job_title name i.e $result['job_title'] using ajax jquery.To do so I need to pass $result ['job_title']'s particular id to ajax jquery source code (hotjoboutput.js)  so that the id could be passed 
to api.php file as ajax url parameter.

> And my api.php file contains:

```
<?php 
include("config.php");
$jobid=$_GET['jobid'];
$sql=mysql_query("select * from hotjobs where job_id='$jobid'");
$count=mysql_num_rows($sql);
if($count==1){
$result=mysql_fetch_array($sql);
 }
 echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

> My hotjoboutput.js contains:

```
    $function getrecord(id){
var jobid=id;
$.ajax({
       url:'api.php?',
       data:"jobid="+jobid,
       dataType:'json',
       success:function(data)
       {
           var jobtitle=data[1];
           var refrence_no=data[2];
           var company=data[3];
           var country=data[4];
           var salary=data[5];
           var salaryincurrency=data[6];
           var dutyhours=data[7];
           var food=data[8];
           var accomodation=data[9];
           var medical=data[10];
           var overtime=data[11];
           var period=data[12];
           var leavedays=data[13];
           var joiningairticket=data[14];
           var returnairticket=data[15];
           var nofvaccancy=data[16];
           var note=data[17]; 
$("#hotjoboutput").html("<p>vaccancy for "+jobtitle+"</p><table border=1px cellpadding=2px><tr><td>Refrence_no</td>td>"+Refrence_no+"</td></tr>
<tr><td>Company</td><td>"+company+"</td></tr>
<tr><td>Country</td><td>"+country+"</td></tr>
<tr><td>Salary</td><td>"+salary+"</td></tr>
<tr><td>Salary in Currency</td><td>"+salaryincurrency+"</td></tr>
<tr><td>Duty </td><td>"+dutyhours+"</td></tr>
<tr colspan=2>Terms and conditions</tr>
<tr><td>Food</td><td>"+food+"</td></tr>
<tr><td>Accomodation</td><td>"+accomodation+"</td></tr>
<tr><td>Medical</td><td>"+medical+"</td></tr>
<tr><td>Overtime</td><td>"+overtime+"</td></tr>
<tr><td>Period of contract</td><td>"+period+"</td></tr>
<tr><td>Leave</td><td>"+leavedays+"</td></tr>
<tr><td>Joining Air Ticket</td><td>"+joiningairticket+"</td></tr>
<tr><td>Return Air Ticket</td><td>"+returnairticket+"</td></tr>
<tr><td>No of vaccancy</td><td>"+nofvaccancy+"</td></tr>
<tr><td>Note</td><td>"+note+"</td></tr>
</table>");
}
});

});
```

I hope i'm clear with my question somehow. Please if anyone can help this guy!

Comment: Your use of mysql is wide open to SQL injection, you do no sanitization or validation of user input and just use it directly in queries.  You also don't check the result of the last sql operation.  The mysql_* functions return something to indicate whether they succeeded or not.  By the way, don't use the mysql_* functions, they're deprecated in all but name.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method would be to throw the ID into an inline click event:

```
<tr><td><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="getrecord(<?php echo (int)$result['job_id']; ?>)"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($result['job_title']);?></a></td></tr>
```

Alternatively you could put the ID in a `data-id` attribute and retrieve it with jQuery:

```
<tr><td><a class="job-title" href="javascript:void(0);" data-id="<?php echo (int)$result['job_id']; ?>"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($result['job_title']);?></a></td></tr>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.job-title').click(function(){
        getrecord($(this).data('id'));
    });
});
```

---

Side note: `mysql_*` is deprecated and you have an SQL Injection vulnerability. Switch to MySQLi or PDO Prepared Statements.

A quick fix would be:

```
$jobid = (int)$_GET['jobid'];
```

I also added `htmlspecialchars()` to prevent XSS.